# Woo commerce change titles on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone direct me to where I can find the file where I can change the "State/County" and "Zip Code" titles in a woocommerce checkout page?

Comment: goto your theme/woocommerce/checkout and search

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce offers hooks for this:
please check [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

as you'll see on that page you can hook a function (that you'll save in your childs functions.php for example ) to WooCommerce checkout page and change the data that is available.

so your code will look something like:

```
/ Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['label'] = 'My new postcode title';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['label'] = 'My new state title';
     return $fields;
}
```

other examples and fields on the linked page.